# Why "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in `return` statement?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

(Minimal javascript experience)

Source pasted into Chrome JavaScript Console:

```
 (function doesIconExist() {
    var xPath = '//*[@id="downloadActivityIcon"]'
    var nodes = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    return (nodes.iterateNext() ? ‘present’ : ‘absent’);
}
 )();
```

The console reports the subject error message and links to this:
[image: image showing location of error]
--which I post as an image to show the squiggly red line.

I tried converting the ternary conditional to an `if` statement:

```
if (nodes.iterateNext())
    return 'present' ;
return 'absent' ;
```

but it generates the same error with the squiggly red line starting in the first `return` under the first `'` and extending through the semicolon.

Comment: The quote characters in the first code sample do not look like proper quotes; they look like "smart" quotes like in Microsoft Word.

Comment: (w/r my replaced comment) Ah, you mean the single quotes in the return statement.  Yes, I overlooked those. I have no idea where they were converted; the code was untouched by MS Word! Good eye -- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As spotted by @Pointy, the single quotes in the `return` statement were of the slanted variety used in word processing. I have no idea how they became so, but correcting them to proper `'` single quotes solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the `` ` `` by `'` or by `"`and your code could look like this :

```js
(function doesIconExist() {
    var xPath = '//*[@id="downloadActivityIcon"]'
    var nodes = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    return (nodes.iterateNext() ? 'present' : 'absent');
}
 )();
```

I personaly tried in my console and it's working.